# How to use the Wordpress Juju charm to add existing database content

Tags: juju, wordpress

I've been looking at the Wordpress juju charm and I'd like to use it to create instances of developer.ubuntu.com for testing and design purposes.

I believe I can use it as-is, apart from one bit: the d.u.c theme requires a copy of the database to be installed. Is this something that I could do with the current charm? Would I need to add anything to it?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with the WordPress charm.